# 'save' does not work, tried flush and failOnError:true but no error was given

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm trying to update a DB with `flush:true` for `save()` operations. The debugger showed that the status was updated, but when I use this sql

```
Select * from domain_name where id = 123
```

I'm still getting the old status.

I am using the Quartz plugin for running a scheduled cron job that reads from the same table:

```
DomainName.withTransaction{ status ->
    try
    {                          
        DomainName name  = DomainName.get(123)  
        name.status = "newstatus"
        name.save(flush:true,failOnError:true)
    }
    catch(Exception rte)
    {   
        log.error "Update failed with error ${rte.message}"
        status.setRollbackOnly()
    }
}
```

Has anyone encountered similar issues? There are no error on turning on hibernate log in config.groovy

```
debug 'org.hibernate.SQL' 
    'org.hibernate.transaction'
```

Comment: Where do you have the save logic?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the flush:true ? When you use withTransaction the session will be flushed in the end of transaction, so you don't need to use flush:true.

Comment: I would recommend you put some logging in to make sure that name.save(flush: true, failOnError: true) is called.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue. Turns out that the instance to update was being obtained via a dynamic finder. Once I used get(id) to obtain the instance the values were save to the database table.

During troubleshooting I turned on the sql logging. When the row was supposed to be updated no update statement was written to the console when the instance was obtained via the finder. Using get(id) the update statement was written to the console.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem resides before your given code block.

Did you pull that object with dirty checking (e.g. `Domain.get()`) before this transaction, which is still alive? My suggestion is to check your code carefully, detach from all dirty check (e.g. use `Domain.discard()`) and try again. That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem. I was getting the object via a dynamic method. Then passing a property to another method. In the other method I was again getting the object by a dynamic finder.

I saved the domain object but it was not getting saved. I tried `failOnError` as well as `flush` but did not work.

I passed the domain object instead of using dynamic finder and it worked.